# TFS Item is showing up 'White'

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am using dark color theme for my Visual Studio 2012 but seems like whenever I am opening up a TFS work item, the color is 'White'. I dont know how to fix this issue. This is how it looks like:

[image: This is how it looks like:]

Comment: Check the event log; Visual Studio has a theme service that provides colors to plugins (including custom work item controls). If there's a problem retrieving the theme information, it'll default to the Light theme. Also, check that C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\TeamExplorer.pkgdef exists... that's the file that contains all of the theme info for Team Explorer.

Comment: @DanielMann: Yes! That exists.